# The language-neutral solution package was not found

Tags: development, error

How repair this error: Please describe.

**The language-neutral solution package was not found.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems something to ask with Google...
[The language-neutral solution package was not found](http://digioz.blogspot.com/2011/04/language-neutral-solution-package-was.html)

Excerpt from the article:

> There are several things you can try to resolve the issue, in this
>   specific order:
>
> 1. Close Visual Studio Solution and completely exit out of it, then run it again and compile. This sometimes fixes the issue.
> 2. Right-Click on your Visual Studio Solution, select "Clean" Solution, then Right Click on SharePoint Project and choose "Retract".
>      Rebuild and Deploy.
> 3. In PowerShell running as Administrator run Uninstall-SPSolution:
>
>    - Unistall-SPSolution -identity {Name of WSP File} -allwebapplications
> 4. In PowerShell running as Administrator run Remove-SPSolution:
>
>    - Remove-SPSolution -identity {Name of WSP File} -force
> 5. In PowerShell running as Administrator run the Delete() command:
>
>    - (Get-SPSolution {Name of WSP File}).Delete()
>
> If items 1 through 4 doesn't fix it, item 5 will definitely do the
>   trick, but it shouldn't be run unless all the other solutions fail.

**NOTE:** Before deleting anything just take backup!

Comment: Yes I tried, but not not can geret with it. Thanks Arslan

Comment: Answers that only contain links are not answers. You must provide a summary of the link.

Comment: That's a very old post :)

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri, yes there are a great many of old posts that need cleaning up on this site! Thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 4):

Run `(Get-SPSolution solutionname.wsp).Delete()` in Sharepoint Management Shell.

You can find your SolutionName using:

```
Get-SPSolution
```

You can also use:

```
Get-SPSolution | select * | out-file c:\solutions.txt
```

This will list all solutions, properties and output them to a file called solutions.txt.
This may solve your problems.